# Can I detect when the Garbage collector works?

Tags: swing, java, garbage-collection

Am working on a swing app.
I will experiance slowness after continuous half an hour of use.

can it because of GC running?

How can i find when the garbage collector runs through any jdk 1.5 commandline option?

Thanks

Comment: This looks like symptoms of memory leakage (which is hard to track at times in java)

Answer (score 9):

When you start Java with -XX:+PrintGC, it will print messages whenever it garbage-collects.

Answer (score 6):

You can use jconsole.exe, which can be found in the bin directory of your jdk. It shows you a lot of details about your running JVM.

Comment: +1 for jconsole.  You'll see a saw tooth graph of memory usage, showing when the GC's kick in.  You can even trigger a manual GC if you like.  I doubt you'll find this is GC rlated though.

Answer (score 4):

It's highly unlikely that the GC is causing observable problems. Once upon a time Java had a horribly slow GC that gave it a near-permanent bad reputation. That time is past.

What exactly is the slowness? A GC should really never take more than a fraction of a second, even for the rare full collection pass.

Edit: Even if the GC *is* running a measurable amount, it's likely only a symptom of the problem. Whatever code is placing that much demand on the GC would internally cause more slowness than the GC will.

Comment: This is only true for small applications, which might be the case here. As soon as you scale up memory usage and therefore GC can easily become a problem. In most cases it is more about the number of garbage collections that about the time it takes a single GC.

Comment: If by small you mean less than *a gig or two*, then maybe?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to investigate this if you use recent JDK is jvisualvm which allow you to attach to a running process.  You can then see garbage collections, memory usage and profile if needed.  (It is essentially the corresponding NetBeans functionality available as a standalone applciation in the JDK).

It complements and enhances jconsole!

(But what you describe may be excessive GC's caused by a memory leak in your program.  Use jvisualvm to figure out)

Answer (score 2):

I strongly doubt it's the GC you are seeing. As [280Z28](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135641/can-i-detect-when-the-garbage-collector-works/1135659#1135659) points out, the GC runs pretty fast usually (though can still kill performance if you're doing something wrong). Are you using the program in that time? If not, maybe you're a little low on memory and it got paged out? (leaving Eclipse running for longer than maybe half a day without using it results in a state I can't work anymore with it. On systems with little memory it might happen sooner).

Answer (score 2):

GC itself probably is not the problem. However, if you have a memory leak, it might result in GC using all CPU trying to clear memory.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has mentioned previously, GC is almost certainly not the problem.

I'd try something like [YJP](http://www.yourkit.com/overview/index.jsp) (Your Java Profiler, free for 30 days) to profile your application and find out what is slowing down.  A memory leak is a very possible cause.